# Cant update CMake on Windows

Tags: windows, cmake

I have tried downloading the installer from the CMake website, and installing with `choco install cmake`.

After refreshing my powershell with `refreshenv` I still get the old version of CMake.  I have tried adding the path to my powershell profile.

Is it because it comes with Visual Studio?

How do I update it?

Comment: is your powershell the visual studio developer prompt and have you installed cmake with your installation of visual studio? if so, there could be a path conflict. try [getting the path of the cmake your powershell is seeing](https://superuser.com/a/676107).

Comment: Type `where.exe cmake` to determine the path to the selected version of CMake. Most likely, it's what @DavidFong said -- you have another copy (namely the Visual Studio-provided one) earlier in the `PATH`.

Comment: If you're using a cmake bundled with visual studio, you might be out of luck in terms of updating. I would recommend just using the visual studio installer to remove the bundled one and use the chocolatey one, which is pretty up-to-date and easy to update in the future via chocolatey.